# Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6 'String_Agg' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute `string_Agg()` function at below mentioned version.

But SQL Server throws this error:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6
> 'String_Agg' is not a recognized built-in function name

Versions used:

```
SQL Server Management Studio                    15.0.18131.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools        15.0.1347.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)         10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML                                 3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                10.0.14393
```

Please help for any workaround for this.

Comment: Please execute SELECT @@VERSION and provide the output

Comment: Please show *how* you are using `string_agg` and also confirm the database's `compatability level`

Comment: The version of management studio is irrelevant. This is just a clientside tool sending the queries to a server. It is the SQL Server that you are connected to that needs to be of high enough version.

Comment: The error message is very clear.  Your SQL Server has no clue what is `String_Agg()`.  You must be running older version.

Answer (score 0):

see the sql server version of the Target Sql Server, by running below command.

```sql
SELECT @@version
```

Or you can run below command to get information about Sql server

```sql
SELECT  
  SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS ComputerName,
  SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS InstanceName,  
  SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition,
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion,  
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel;  
GO
```

if you see, [STR_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is supported only from **SQL Server 2017(version 14.x)** onwards.

[image]